# Accent keys immediately being written instead of waiting for another key press

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, keyboard-layout

Background: I'm using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu 22.04. My keyboard layout is US (English) QWERTY.

I recently installed Ubuntu on a VM and have been using it without problems for a few days, however, I accidentally pressed something that made the accent keys (`,~,',",^) appear immediately after I pressed them instead of waiting for another key press, like a letter or the spacebar.

The same happens when I use Ubuntu's virtual keyboard.

I uninstalled Ubuntu and the VM, but after I reinstall, the problem is still there.

I've searched the forum for an answer but had no luck. Just to be clear, this is not a keyboard layout problem. I tried changing to US (International) but the problem remained.

Comment: I would like to know *exactly* which keyboard layout you are using. So can you please edit your question and show the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`